# Nginx Proxy Manager redirects hosted website to 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: redirect, nginx-reverse-proxy, openresty, http-status-code-502

I have a website running where I use Nginx Proxy Manager to redirect to this website. However, as soon as I hit my website I get the following message:

[image]

Does anyone have a clue what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I came to the following conclusion. I think from my experience it can mean two things:

- Either your website/docker container is not running
- Or Nginx cannot find an index.html file on the main root of web address 'example.com'.

However, [hostinger.com](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/502-bad-gateway) points out the following:

- Unresolved domain name
- Server overload
- Browser issues
- Home-network equipment error
- Firewall blocks

So make sure that index.html is present for your website and you have trouble shooted your container where you are 100% sure that docker container has no exceptions, errors and runs perfectly fine. Try use something like 'docker-compose logs' where the docker-compose.yml is located (this only works for a running docker container)