# How to use a reverse proxy with Nerdctl

Tags: reverse-proxy, nerdctl

I have been trying to setup Nginx in a container using Nerdctl and it doesn't work because of some [slight differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75950403/46810) with the way Nerdctl handles DNS.

Forcing that is getting involved, so I've looked into using Traefik instead but that fails as it tries to use the docker.sock file/socket as a way to update it's routing. I tried to fake the socket with just a shared file, then the containerd.sock, but the first would never be updated, and the second has issues with rootless containers accessing / modifying it.

Is there a better proxy to use inside a bridge network with Nerdctl.